# Retrieve multiple data and display to a single row

Tags: php, html, sql

I have my table below which is the result from my query,

```
Status |Tasks|Owner|Details
-------------------------------
OnGoing|test |test |2016-09-01
                    test a
OnGoing|test |test |2016-09-02
                    test b
OnGoing|test |test |2016-09-03
                    test c
```

What I want to happen is that if the Tasks is like `test` and Status is like `OnGoing` it will show up in a single row under Details column below,

```
Status |Tasks|Owner|Details
-------------------------------
OnGoing|test |test |2016-09-01
                    test a
                    2016-09-02
                    test b
                    2016-09-03
                    test c
```

My current query is,

```
$sql="SELECT date, status, task, owner, details
        FROM tracker
        WHERE date BETWEEN '" . $date . "' AND '" . $date1 . "'
        ORDER BY date, status";
```

And here is the code for my table,

```
echo "<table width='auto' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='0px' border=1 align='center'>
<tr>
<th align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'><font color='#FFFFFF'><strong>Status</strong></font></th>
<th align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'><font color='#FFFFFF'><strong>Tasks</strong></font></th>
<th align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'><font color='#FFFFFF'><strong>Owner/s</strong></font></th>
<th align='center' style='border:dotted 1px;' bgcolor='#66CC00'><font color='#FFFFFF'><strong>Details</strong></font></th>
</tr>"; 

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
{
{
$status = $result['status'];
$status = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $status);
$status = str_replace("\r", "<br>", $status);
$status = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $status);

$task = $result['task'];
$task = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $task);
$task = str_replace("\r", "<br>", $task);
$task = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $task);

$owner = $result['owner'];
$owner = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $owner);
$owner = str_replace("\r", "<br>", $owner);
$owner = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $owner);

$date = $result['date'];
$date = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $date);
$date = str_replace("\r", "<br>", $date);
$date = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $date);

$details = $result['details'];
$details = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $details);
$details = str_replace("\r", "<br>", $details);
$details = str_replace("\n", "<br>", $details);

echo "<form action='get_test.php' method='post'>";
echo"<tr>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $result['status'] . "<input type=hidden name=status value=" . $result['status'] . " </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $result['task'] . "<input type=hidden name=task value=" . $result['task'] . " </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $result['owner'] . "<input type=hidden name=owner value=" . $result['owner'] . " </td>";
echo  
"<td align='left' width='auto'>
" . $date . "<input type=hidden name=date value=" . htmlspecialchars($date) . " /><br>
" . $details . "<input type=hidden name=details value=" . htmlspecialchars($details) . " /> </td>";
"</tr>"; 
echo "</form>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), e.g.

```
select status, task, owner, group_concat(date, details order by date separator ' ')
from tracker
where date between '" . $date . "' and '" . $date1 . "'
group by status, task, owner
order by status
```

Comment: thank you for your help but im getting this error:
`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tracker\get_test.php on line 64`

Comment: This is a different error. Upfront, you should not use `mysql_*` functions, because they are deprecated and removed in PHP 7. [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) wants the result from `mysql_query` as its first parameter, but you give it an array.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this coding stuff...any idea how can i fix the error given with my code above?

Comment: There's a detailed PHP online manual with examples. A complete mysqli example can be found at [mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php#example-1924).

Comment: You may also look through Stackoverflow documentation on [PHP/mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=php&query=mysqli)